# word processor that uses \LaTeX for equations

Tags: rendering

just curious.

I use `\LaTeX` here and at wikipedia for equations.  I would like to use it in a word processor (instead of that crappy Equation Editor).

is there an app or an online app that i can write and format prose and insert equations using `LaTeX`?  and then "print" to pdf?

Comment: I don't think this is possible ...

Comment: Do you mean services like [this](https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) or [this](https://www.latex4technics.com/)?

Comment: Of course, `pdflatex` is the "app" that "can write and format prose and insert equations using `LaTeX`".  Its output is already pdf. On a PC platform, MikTeX is a typical version of that app: https://miktex.org/

Comment: Would LyX be something you'd consider. Don't know too much about LyX, it may not meet your specification, but it could be another way of getting what you want?

Comment: the services @totera refers to will render me an equation that i can somehow copy the rendered image and paste into a word processor (like pasting in a picture).  i was hoping for something like Word or Appleworks but does not use that lame Equation Editor but would use TeX instead.

Comment: I remember in 2012 when I was conducting my thesis. My supervisor introduced me to Latex. From that time, I never touched it word processor again for any work. Latex does every thing a writer needs. At the start, it is intimidating but later on it is worthwhile. For your question, just insert your equation as an image (i.e. take a look at `standalone` package)  in that stupid app. No wonder it is for free if you have Outlook account.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a mac, then [LaTeXiT](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/17889/latexit) might be what you're looking for. It lets you write things out in TeX/LaTeX, and turn whatever you write into a picture or PDF, which you can then insert into your document. It's a life-saver.

I haven't used it, but apparently [KLatexFormula](http://klatexformula.sourceforge.net) is the Windows equivalent.

Comment: thanks.  not that i am using a *current* mac, but in either case (mac, win, linux) how are the equations stored in case you want to edit your paper.  do i have to store each equation source (in LaTeX) as a separate little file?  is there any way to have the LaTeX source live with the prose of the text in a single editable file?

Comment: I don't know of a way to make it live in the editor itself (unless it's emacs' org-mode). LaTeXiT essentially is for one-off use. In other words, you write the code, you compile it, and it spits out a tiny PDF or png or (insert image file type here). Then, you close LaTeXiT and it's gone. You could store the code in various small files and open them with the application, but it's for just quickly generating small snippets.

Comment: "It lets you write things out in TeX/LaTeX , and turn whatever you write into a picture or PDF" TeX/LateX do that too. no need for third party.

Comment: Sorry, should've been more specific. It doesn't format the full page, just what you give it.

Comment: okay, so i got and installed KLatexFormula and ran it.  i type in a couple letters into the **Enter LaTeX expression** box and when i push **Run LaTeX** button i get an error window that says: *Can't query version of ghostscript located at `'*.

Comment: Presumably that means that somewhere in you KLatexFormula preferences, you need to set your path to GhostScript.